# group and count in python

Tags: python, count, grouping

I am trying to get group by and count in python. It does not seem to group for some reason

Using python 2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
counts = {}
logfile = open("/tmp/test.out", "r")

for line in logfile:
    if line.startswith("20") in line:
        seq = line.strip()
        substr = seq[0:13]
        if substr not in counts:
            counts[substr] = 0
            counts[substr] += 1
            for substr, count in counts.items():
                print(count,substr)
```

I would like output like below grouped by count

```
 6 2019-06-17T00
 13 2019-06-17T01
  9 2019-06-17T02
  7 2019-06-17T03
  6 2019-06-17T04
```

Comment: Can you a sample of the file's contents and the output you're getting for it?

Comment: The file got many random lines..I am picking up only lines like below ```2019-06-19T09:56:04.378+0000: [Times: user=153.84 sys=1.15, real=18.13 secs] 
2019-06-19T09:59:46.370+0000: [Times: user=154.93 sys=1.24, real=18.65 secs] ```
2019-06-19T10:00:05.074+0000: [Times: user=155.21 sys=1.39, real=20.03 secs]

Comment: I am interested in only the hour and the counts of the occurrences..thanks

Comment: and I am getting the below output and it not grouped   ```('2019-06-16T10', 1)
('2019-06-15T19', 1)
('2019-06-16T13', 1)
('2019-06-16T12', 1)```

Comment: The problem is the IF line (if substr not in counts:)

Comment: Your indentation is messed up

Answer (score 2):

You have the substring incrementing indented one block too far

```py
for line in logfile:
    if line.startswith("20") in line:
        seq = line.strip()
        substr = seq[0:13]
        if substr not in counts:
            counts[substr] = 0
        # Un-indented below
        counts[substr] += 1

# Print output only after loop completes
for substr, count in counts.items():
    print(count,substr)
```

Before you would only do the increment if the substring was not in the count dictionary.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree unless they want to see the progress on each iteration, so I left it there.

Comment: Thanks Sam that works..the out seems to be looping continuously ```('2019-06-17T05', 1)
('2019-06-17T03', 7)
('2019-06-17T07', 1)
('2019-06-17T06', 3)
('2019-06-16T02', 1)
('2019-06-16T00', 1)
('2019-06-17T02', 10)```

Comment: The desired output does not indicate that they want to see it at every iteration

Comment: Looking for something uniq count...I do this in unix to achieve this..awk '{print substr($1,1,13)}' | sort | uniq -c

Comment: @user345270 Does this answer work properly now? Is there something that is not working still?

Comment: The code works..thanks Sam. But the count does not look right. Does not seem same as uniq-c . I will check further

Comment: @user345270. The uniq pipeline you showed doesn't filter the lines starting with 20

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {}
logfile = open("/tmp/test.out", "r")

for line in logfile:
    if line.startswith("20") in line:
        seq = line.strip()
        substr = seq[0:13]
        if substr not in counts:
            counts[substr] = 0
        counts[substr] += 1
for substr, count in counts.items():
    print(count,substr)
```

I think this would work

Comment: Why should that work? An explanation is more valuable than the solution, especially when your solution is basically a copy of the existing answer.

Comment: basically at the end of complete iteration of the file that you we opened we want to print the number of the times we encounter the string that starts with "20".

Comment: what your solution is does is it prints the string in each iteration, so if there are 50 lines in the file so your loop iterate through 50 times and print each time ...it you want to do so that why are you counting the string.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you updated your solution after seeing my solution so basically you copied my solution.

Comment: @user345270 if this solution worked for you than you may mark this solution as write.

Comment: It's not my solution. It was my comment that fixed it.

Comment: First of all, I didn't see your comment(when i am writing the my solution). and you can see the time when i answer is posted and when the above answer is edited.

As it is the same code for count the number of words in the file or counting the number of distinct words in the file.